# Viewing contents of OLAP DML program

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, olap, toad

I have come across the following stored procedure within an Oracle database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRICING.sp_run_interface
as
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
dbms_aw.execute('aw attach bewpsp ro');
dbms_aw.execute('aw attach bewpsd ro');
dbms_aw.execute('run.interface');
dbms_aw.execute('aw detach noq bewpsp');
dbms_aw.execute('aw detach noq bewpsd');
END;
/
```

After much research, I believe that these statements are executing an [OLAP DML Program](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/olap.101/b10339/program001.htm).  However I've no idea how to actually view the contents of these programs, or indeed where they are stored.

I'm using TOAD and would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this code is first attaching 2 analytic workspaces, running a program, and then detaching them again.

Oracle Analytic Workspaces has now been superseeded by Oracle OLAP.

You'll need to find someone to show you how to navigate the analytic workspaces most likely via analytic workspace manager. Then just type `edt run.interface` and this will show you the contents of the run.interface program.

Hope this helps!

Regards,

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Run the following PL/SQL

```
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);

  dbms_aw.execute('aw attach bewpsp ro');

  dbms_aw.execute('aw attach bewpsd ro');

  dbms_aw.execute('describe run.interface');

  dbms_aw.execute('aw detach noq bewpsp');

  dbms_aw.execute('aw detach noq bewpsd');

END;
```

Or you can use [Analytic Workspace Manager](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/olap/olap-downloads-098860.html) to view the program.  Choose the Tools/OLAP Worksheet command and type the following:

```
aw attach bewpsp ro

aw attach bewpsd ro

describe run.interface

or 

aw attach bewpsp ro

aw attach bewpsd ro


edit run.interface
```